# Images repeated in GridView

Tags: java, android

I have a list of 6 distinct images. To display these images in GridView, I have a custom adapter. Now the problem is, only the 1st image is repeatedly showing in GridView instead of all distinct images.
Here is my `getView()`

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_grid, null, false);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int) (width / 2.05), (int) (height /4.6)));
        convertView.setPadding(1,1,1,2);
        ImageView thumb = convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbs);
        Log.i(TAG, "getView: "+mthumbs.size()+mthumbs.get(0)+mthumbs+getItem(5));
        Picasso.with(mActivity).load(mthumbs.get(position)).into(thumb);
    } else {
        convertView = convertView;
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: `Log.i(TAG, "getView: "+mthumbs.size()+mthumbs.get(0)+mthumbs+getItem(5));` what does it print in log?

Comment: the values are redundant here

Comment: In your adapter constructor log all values, make sure they are distinct

Comment: in my adapter i receive the redundant values but in my activity if i check the list the values are different

Comment: know that, but check these values in your adapter CONSTRUCTOR

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing below method in your adapter.
Please add this below method to your adapter.

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
}
```

Comment: i added this method but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` will be called on your adapter zero to many times per position, and the convertView it supplies may be a reusable instance.

Since you're only ever setting the content when the supplied convertView child is null, you're effectively removing the adapter's functionality and only setting an image for the last element to be called when the convertView was still null.

Move the following code outside of that if/else check:

```
ImageView thumb = convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbs);
Log.i(TAG, "getView: "+mthumbs.size()+mthumbs.get(0)+mthumbs+getItem(5));
Picasso.with(mActivity).load(mthumbs.get(position)).into(thumb);
```

You're also going to want to look into the [ViewHolder pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling) to make it work more efficiently (you were almost there with the attempt to reuse the convertView).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the use of getItem(int) , getCount() & getItemId(int) .

"getCount()" - Should return size of Adapter.

getItem(int) - Normally, should return the actual object at the specified position in the adapter.

"getItemId(int)" - Should return the row id of the item.